Trying to replicate this with wheelchart to easy include text in each space

Hello, community. I have created this chart, and I plan to write text in each space. I think it's possible to recreate it with the wheelchart package to make writing text in the boxes easier. Still, although I have managed to nest three wheels with twelve squares in each without problem, I have not been capable of making the central boxes (N, S, E, W) vertical and not radial. Does anyone have any idea how to do it?
Here is the MWE of the chart made without wheelchart.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shapes.misc}

\tikzset{cruz/.style={cross out, draw, minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, rotate=0},
cross/.default={1pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   every node/.append style={circle, draw=black, inner sep=5cm, minimum size=1cm, line width=0.5pt}]
\node[inner sep=3cm] (2) at (0,0) {};
\node[inner sep=4cm] (3) at (0,0) {};
\node[inner sep=5cm] (4) at (0,0) {};
\node[name=xcross, cruz=5.025cm, draw=black, line width=0.5pt] {};
\def\firstcircle{ (0,0) circle (7.07cm) } 
\def\firstsquare{ (-0.759,-7.06) rectangle (0.759,7.06)}
\def\secondsquare{ (-7.06,-0.759) rectangle (7.06,0.759)}
\begin{scope}       
    \clip \firstcircle;     
    \draw[black] \firstsquare;      
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}       
    \clip \firstcircle;     
    \draw[black] \secondsquare;      
\end{scope}
\node[inner sep=2cm, fill=white] (1) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Here is the code using wheelchart:
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usepackage {siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\wheelchart[
contour=black,
wheel lines={black!50,thick},
data{list}={l,k,j,i,h,g,f,e,d,c,b,a},
slices style{list}={White},
total count=12,
radius={4}{2},
start half=60
]{}

\wheelchart[
contour=black,
wheel lines={black!50,thick},
data{list}={xii,xi,x,ix,viii,vii,vi,v,iv,iii,ii,i},
slices style{list}={White},
total count=12,
radius={6}{4},
start half=60
]{}

\wheelchart[
contour=black,
wheel lines={black!50,thick},
data{list}={12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1},
slices style{list}={White},
total count=12,
radius={8}{6},
start half=60
]{}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Thank you in advance.

welcome! your code doesn't seem to use the wheelchart package at all? you said you've managed to recreate some of what you want already, so please show us that code.

Yes, of course! I have modified my original question by adding the requested code.

The answer below uses the wheelchart package, which I wrote.
The keys contour=black and slices style{list}={White} are replaced by slices style={draw,fill=none}.
In the key radius={4}{2} the values are changed because the first argument corresponds to the inner radius and the second argument to the outer radius and similarly for other instances of the key radius.
The key wheel lines is removed.
The key data is set empty and instead the key wheel data is used.
The key total count is removed. Instead, the text is placed inside the command \wheelchart.
The positioning of the horizontal and vertical lines can be changed with the value \a.
The ordering of the text is changed and the key counterclockwise is used.
The lines \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} and \usepackage {siunitx} have been removed because these are unnecessary in this example.
The shape of the slices is modified with the keys slices inner angle reduce till slices outer start angle shift. The values for these keys can be determined with trigonometry.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\NewDocumentCommand\defvalues{mm}{%
\edef\r{#1}%
\edef\R{#2}%
\edef\b{\fpeval{atand(sind(75-acosd(\a/\r))/(\r/\R-cosd(75-acosd(\a/\r))))}}%
\edef\c{\fpeval{-atand(sind(acosd(\a/\R)-75)/(\r/\R-cosd(acosd(\a/\R)-75)))}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\edef\a{\fpeval{2*cosd(55)}}%this value can be customized
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  counterclockwise,
  data=,
  radius={\r}{\R},
  slices inner angle reduce{1,4,7,10}=\b,
  slices inner end angle shift{3,6,9,12}=\b,
  slices inner start angle shift{2,5,8,11}=-\b,
  slices outer angle reduce{1,4,7,10}=\c,
  slices outer end angle shift{3,6,9,12}=\c,
  slices outer start angle shift{2,5,8,11}=-\c,
  slices style={draw,fill=none},
  start half,
  value=1,
  wheel data=\WCvarA,
  wheel data pos=0.5
}
\defvalues{2}{4}
\wheelchart{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l}
\defvalues{4}{6}
\wheelchart{i,ii,iii,iv,v,vi,vii,viii,ix,x,xi,xii}
\defvalues{6}{8}
\wheelchart{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you very much, @matexmatics, for your detailed response and the magnificent package you have created. I have learned a lot from your comments.
